# Force Landscape ExcelPackage c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excelpackage

I wanted to generate Excel sheets from C#, so I used the ExcelPackage libraries to do so. Everything works fine and I am able to generate and download the sheet.

The last thing I want to achieve is setting the sheet from *Portrait* to *Landscape* mode.
Is there a way to do this, using ExcelPackage? I tried searching the documentation, but didn't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExcelPackage doesn't have the possibility to set an Excel sheet in portrait mode using c#.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible!
And this is how is have to be made:

```
 workSheetByRight.PrinterSettings.Orientation = eOrientation.Landscape;
```

Where workSheetByRight is of type - ExcelWorksheet